# What is the best way to manage trusted device for multiple Apple accounts?

Tags: icloud

Apple Developer website requires the account to have a trusted device. I'm using personal iCloud account associated with all my Apple devices but the Apple Developer account belongs to the company.

I have identified my personal workstation as a trusted device for this company iCloud account. This means I have to log out from iCloud of my MacBook every time someone has to log in to the Apple Developer website.

Is there like an app that entrust the device as a trusted device to get login code without having to sign out iCloud?